# Inflate/control Widgets in an activity's layout from a fragment

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an android music player with an interface that's similar to Google play music. It has 3 fragments; SongsFragment, ArtistFragment and AlbumsFragments in a TabLayout controlled by ViewPager.

I have implemented a slidingUpPanel which contains the play/pause, next, prev etc widgets.

I can play songs from each of these fragments, However, I can't control the widgets inside the sliding up panel because its xml layout cannot be referenced or inflated from these fragments.

How do I play songs from each fragment and get a reference to the widgets and/or pass data to it?